# How to create an input field and then prepopulate the field with

Tags: javascript

Please no jquery.

I've seen several examples of this where the input field already exists on the page before you update it, but I'd like to dynamically create the input field and then populate it with information available from the page (hence current_value variable defined above this code snippet):

```
for (i=0; i<tables.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    var sp = document.createElement('span');
    var act_table = document.createElement('table');
    act_table.id = 'act-tests-' + i;
    act_table.style.display = 'none';

    var test_name_input = document.createElement('tr');
    test_name_input.innerHTML = '<tr><td width="100px">Name</td><td><input type="text" class="wideValue testName input"></td></tr>';
    test_name_input.setAttribute('value', current_rule);

    act_table.innerHTML ='<tbody><tr>LOTS OF TABLE ROWS HERE</tr></tbody>';
    act_table.insertBefore(test_name_input,act_table.firstChild);
    sp.appendChild(act_table);
}
```

The field is being shown but not populated with my current_value.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you set an attribute to the `tr`, instead of the created input field.
try to do this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input")[you_index].setAttribute("value", current_value);
```

Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/35g0ks0t/

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out in a few hours when I can get back to it.